# GWT send Header to c# Backend

Tags: c#, rest, gwt

I try to send a custom header to backend like this:

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
builder.setHeader("X-SessionID", "ABC123456");
```

And will recieve it by:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{

}
```

But the 'Message' object is empty! What do i wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check in Chrome Dev Tools if the request has actually a body? 
Where and how do you set the body of your `RequestBuilder` ?

Comment: I dont give it a body, don't need one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was CORS Error! I disabled te OPTION Method! So he can't send it correctly!

Enabled the OPTION Method, everything is working fine!